# How to input matrices when posting questions at Math StackExchange?

Tags: support, mathjax

I would like to post a question here in which I would like to insert a $2 \times 2$ matrix with entries $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, respectively, in the positions row 1 col. 1, row 1 col. 2, row 2 col 1, and row 2 col 2. How to?

I would also like to input a general $m \times n$ matrix with entires $a_{ij}$, where $i = 1, 2, \ldots, m$, $j = 1, 2, \ldots, n$.

Comment: Zev Chonoles, instead of closing down my question right away, please point out the exact place in this tutorial where I can look for my desired information. I think I've already gone through it.

Comment: [This page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Comment: The exact place in this tutorial which concerns matrices is linked in robjohn's answer below. It is this link: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5023#5023

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a couple of ways: `\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}`
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}
$$
or
`\left[\begin{array}{l}a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right]`
$$
\left[\begin{array}{l}a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right]
$$
The latter gives you control of the alignment of the elements (eg: l,c,r) and column and row separators.

For more details [see the MathJax tutorial on matrices](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5023).

Note that if there is some MathJax in a post whose source you would like to see, simply right-click on the rendered MathJax and choose "Show Math As > TeX Commands"